# Location of executable file formed after compiling a C program

Tags: gcc, c

I have compiled my C source code using:

```
gcc filename.c
```

It got compiled, but I cannot see the executable in the same directory where my source code is. But when I compile my program using:

```
gcc filename.c -o filename
```

I was able to see my executable file. When I used the first method, where was my executable stored?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't give an explicit `-o` option, the default should be a file called `a.out`. The GNU compiler manual page `man gcc` explains it thus:

```
-o file
    Place output in file file.  This applies to whatever sort of output
    is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object
    file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

    If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in
    a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler
    file in source.s, a precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch,
    and all preprocessed C source on standard output.
```